# On 'grunt' .It should open the browser automatically with url 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/'

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have tried this code. I have installed all the dependencies. But it is not opening the browser, whereas the nodemon task is run and server has started automatically. But the browser is not opening automatically.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
// configure nodemon
    nodemon: {
        dev: {
            script: 'server.js'

        }
    },
    open: {
        dev: {
            path: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
            app: 'Firefox'
        }
    }
});
// load nodemon
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');

// register the nodemon task when we run grunt
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['nodemon', 'open']);
};
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which OS are you using? And what happens when you `grunt -v` ?

Comment: Ubuntu. On   grunt -v  Its giving     

GET /browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1459427521730-13 404

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu here as well; running `grunt open` prints the following error:

```
Running "open:dev" (open) task
Warning: Command failed: Firefox "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"
/bin/sh: 1: Firefox: not found
```

But `firefox` instead of `Firefox` works:

```
open: {
  dev: {
    path: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
    app: 'firefox'
  }
}
```

**Edit:** I did not check the date of this question :( However, maybe my answer helps someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be something like:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['nodemon:dev', 'open:dev']);
```